# Where to define properties in SpringBoot which are common across all environments?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have few properties common to all environments (Ex. `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor`) which I have kept in application.properties under resource directory.

I have DB properties defined in environment based properties file which I pass externally through command line while starting the app:

```
java -jar -Dspring.config.location=<path-to-file> mySpringBootProject.jar
```

However, `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor` is not being set when I am passing properties file externally.

Do I need to define common properties even in external file? 
Or is there a way I can define them in a single place which is reused when not overridden?

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiple profiles to do this. For example, create property files:

```
application-dev.properties
application-prod.properties
application.properties
```

Place your environment-specific properties in the `application-${env}.properties` file and your common properties in `application.properties`.

There are multiple ways to tell spring which profiles to use, for example the `--spring.profiles.active` flag.

See the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config) for more details about the property file search order.

Answer (score 0):

`application.properties` will normally be overridden by Boot projects. Instead, you can add a properties file in a non-conflicting location (such as `src/main/resources/my/package/foo.properties`) and use `@PropertySource` on your autoconfiguration file to add it.

Answer (score 0):

Properties is a file extension for files mainly used in Java related technologies to store the **configurable parameters** of an application. The advantage of using properties file is, we can configure things which are **environment specific** (or are prone to change over a period of time) without the need of changing anything in code. Hence inheriting common properties is **not a good approach**. *If a property seems to be static for all e.g. environments, then it shouldn't be a property.*

But, it could be we have multiple development environments and production, where we would **share same properties in the environments meant for development** purposes and different properties for production. In this case we could create a common properties file and inherit it in all our environment specific properties files. Another scenario could be, that **at the moment of development the property is same for all environments**, but we would like to provide the option of changing it in the future, when required.