# Reuse application.properties from main for test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my spring boot application I have several property files like `application.properties`, `application-prod.properties` or `application-docker.properties` in both directories `src/main/java` as well as `src/test/java`.

Many of the settings are equal in all configurations. Like `server.port=8181` or `notification-email.subject=[ABC] Notification for...` but I have to repeat them in the `application.properties` in **main** and **test**.

How can I avoid maintaining the equal values for main an test?
Can I define something like a `base-application.properties` or *inherit* the properties from the **main** `application.properties` in **test** `application.properties`?

Comment: put all the defaults in `application.properties` and override in the profile specific one. The `application.properties` is loaded always and profile specific ones will override properties from that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to define properties in SpringBoot which are common across all environments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53229229/where-to-define-properties-in-springboot-which-are-common-across-all-environment)

Comment: Thanks for your hints. I clarified the problem I have with main and test.